# Automation tests for "Assign to" feature(button)

Tags: javascript

I am really new to JS and i have to create tests for assign to button, if anyone have experience in this or could help somehow, that would be great and i will be grateful

Comment: What have you tried? There are plenty of resources about Javascript testing on the net. Try a few then come back if you have a specific problem that we can help to resolve.

Comment: Currently i am out ideas, i have created autotesting framework using c# earlier, now i want to get a new job. Bigger issue is to imagine a lot of ways to test this "Assign to" feature (that's my current task)

Comment: Removed unnecessary tags